# How to make a service funtion syncronus in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I'm working with a project using mean.js stack. And I need to make a function that I can use in every other module. I've been reading and what I've found was that I have to make the function as a service. Right this is how I have my service `getSchoolByUser()`:

```
angular.module('schools').factory('Schools', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {
    return $resource('api/schools/:schoolId', {
      schoolId: '@id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      },
      getSchoolByUser: {
        url: 'api/schoolByUser/:schoolPrincipalId',
        params: {
            schoolPrincipalId: 'schoolPrincipalId'
        },
        isArray: false
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

This function I going to use it every time I create a new catalogue. This is an example that how I use it on my CourseController to create a new Course:

```
angular.module('courses')
  .controller('CoursesController', ['$scope',
    '$stateParams',
    '$location', 'Authentication',
    'Courses','Schools',

    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Courses, Schools) {
      $scope.authentication = Authentication;


      // Create new course
      $scope.create = function(isValid) {
        $scope.error = null;

        if (!isValid) {
          $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity', 'courseForm');

          return false;
        }

        var course = new Courses($scope.course);

        $scope.school = Schools.getSchoolByUser({schoolPrincipalId: $scope.authentication.user.id
        }, function () {
          course.SchoolId = $scope.school.id;
          console.log(course);
          course.$save(function(response) {
            //some code here
          }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
          });
        });
      };

    }
  ]);
```

Is there a way that I can go this in a synchronous way with a return inside of the function so I can assign it directly to the scope and the just proceed to save like this:

```
course.SchoolId = getSchoolByUser();
course.$save(function(response) {
```

Comment: basically, you are asking how to make AJAX synchronous?

Comment: I suppose I'm not familiar with ajax :( sorry

Comment: So you don't want an _asynchronous_ service call?

Comment: that's a problem then

Comment: you could make that in to a promise and on the callback from the promise continue to your next piece of code

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Well I just thought that may be a way to make a not asynchronus function, the code works. Just to clean up the code in the controller and call my function every time I need

Comment: AJAX calls [can be made synchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests), but this feature isn't supported by Angular intentionally, because it is terrible practice. Just use promises like it usually done in such cases.

Comment: I''l try it with promises, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use $q service of angularjs(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to make this happen.